# Figure title with underline by LaTeXStrings.jl and PyPlot.jl

Tags: julia

I want to generate a figure whose title is rendered by `LaTeXStrings.jl`

However, when I try to use `\underline`, ValueError is returned.

What should I do?

Sample code is

```
using PyPlot
using LaTeXStrings

title = L"\underline{\theta}"

fig, ax = subplots()
ax[:plot](randn(100))
ax[:set_title](title, useTex=true)
```

The error is

```
PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
ValueError(u'\n\\underline{\\theta}\n^\nUnknown symbol: \\underline (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `rc("text", usetex=true)` solves the issue

Comment: What is `rc` in relation to your sample code? I'm running into the same error and am searching how to solve this - could you please update your answer with a fully working example?